# Inputing "X/O" inTic Tac Toe Game in Python

Tags: python, input, tic-tac-toe

I am trying to code for a tic tac toe game and am having difficulty printing an "X" on the template...My board is set up so that it has an x-axis and y-axis and I am trying to ask the user to input an x-value and y-value and use that x and y value to print an "X" in the correct are of the board...Can someone help me?

```
def printboard(board):
    print("     0   1   2  ")
    print()
    print(" 0   " + board[0][0] + " | " + board[0][1] +" | " + board[0][2] +" ")
    print("    ---+---+---")
    print(" 1   " + board[1][0] + " | " + board[1][1] +" | " + board[1][2] +" ")
    print("    ---+---+---")
    print(" 2   " + board[2][0] + " | " + board[2][1] +" | " + board[2][2] +" ")
    print()


def isBoardFull(board):
    print(board)
    if board[0][0]== board[0][1] == board[0][2] != " "\
            or board[1][0]== board[1][1] == board[1][2] !=" "\
            or board[2][0]== board[2][1] == board[2][2] !=" "\
            or board[0][0]== board[1][0] == board[2][0] != " "\
            or board[0][1]== board[1][1] == board[2][1] !=" "\
            or board[0][2]== board[1][2] == board[2][2] !=" "\
            or board[0][0]== board[1][1]== board[2][2] !=" "\
            or board [0][2]== board[1][1]== board[2][0] !=" ":
        print("board is full")
        return isBoardFull==True
    else:
        return isBoardFull==False

def isHorizontalTicTacToe(board):
        if board[0][0]== board[0][1] == board[0][2] != " "\
        or board[1][0]== board[1][1] == board[1][2] !=" "\
        or board[2][0]== board[2][1] == board[2][2] !=" ":
            print("You won!")
#isHorizontalTicTacToe([[" "," ", " "],["X", "X", "X"],[" ", " ", " "]])

def isVerticalTicTacToe(board):
    if board[0][0]== board[1][0] == board[2][0] != " "\
    or board[0][1]== board[1][1] == board[2][1] !=" "\
    or board[0][2]== board[1][2] == board[2][2] !=" ":
        print("You won!")
#isVerticalTicTacToe([[" ","X", " "],[" ", "X", " "],[" ", "X", " "]])    




def isDiagonalTicTacToe(board):
    if board[0][0]== board[1][1]==board[2][2] !=" "\
        or board [0][2]== board[1][1]==board[2][0] !=" ":
            print("You won!")
#isDiagonalTicTacToe([[" "," ", "X"],[" ", "X", " "],["X", " ", " "]])





def playerMove(board):
    printboard([[" "," ", " "],[" ", " ", " "],[" ", " ", " "]])
    print("Player 1 will be X")
    print("Player 2 will be O")
    playerOneH=int(input("Player One, enter X coordinates of move "))
    playerOneV=int(input("Player One, enter Y coordinates of move "))
    printboard[playerOneH,playerOneV]="X"
playerMove(1)

def playOneGame():
    printboard([[" "," ", " "],[" ", " ", " "],[" ", " ", " "]])
    #playerOneH=input("Player One, enter a horizontal coordinates for the first move ")
    #playerOneV=input("Now enter a vertical coordinate for the first move ")

#playOneGame()

def main():
    # this function should contain a loop that runs playOneGame until the user says he does not want to play anymore
    pass
```

Comment: One thing I noticed: `return isBoardFull == True` probably doesn't do what you think it does. It compares a function to the boolean value True, and returns the result (False). Just enter `return True` or `return False` appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of your bug, in your printBoard function you are assigning a value to a function but you want to assign it to the data structure (board)

```
printboard[playerOneH,playerOneV]="X"
```

should be

```
board[playerOneH][playerOneV]="X"
printboard(board)
```

Answer (score 0):

Think closely what each function call should do, as in: What parameters should it get, and what should it return. (And, if it should create output or read input).

Example:

```
def playerMove(board):
```

What is board? I would have kind of expected that it is a representation of a tic-tac-toe board, for example list of three lists of three characters each.

But then you call it with

```
playerMove(1)
```

That's an integer, not a board representation.

For example, you might decide that the function should allow a single player to make a single move on a persistent board. Then you would define it something like this:

```
def playerMove(board, player):
    x = int(input("Player {}, please enter x: ".format(player)))
    y = int(input("Player {}, please enter y: ".format(player)))
    # Check whether x, y is a valid choice, that is: not yet taken
    board[x][y] = 'X' if player == 1 else 'O'
```

Because a list is mutable, board will get updated. Then you'd need some sort of loop to play the game:

```
def playGame():
    board = [[' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' ']]
    finished = False
    player = 1
    while not finished:
        printboard(board)
        playerMove(board, player)
        # Check for win/end, set finished accordingly
        player = 3 - player # Switches between 1 and 2
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I just have one more quick question what would i put as my parameter for board when I am calling the playerMove function?

Comment: Together with your printboard routine, these two routines are already a very basic tic tac toe game. Of course you still need the win/end condition and a check whether the player does a valid move. But what I want you to do is to carefully think about how each function is meant to be used, before you even write the first line of a function. In the case of the `playerMove` routine, it needs to update the board, so it needs the board, and it needs to know the active player, so it needs that as well. So the parameters are board and player.

Comment: To check the validity of the move, you would need another function. That function should check whether at position `x, y` there is a space in the `board`. So you need the `board` and the `x` and `y`. Other that playerMove, it needs to return something, for example True if you can go there, and false if you can't (location taken, or outside board).

Comment: Ok I got that set up but I can't get the board to print with the "Xs on the screen.. it just keeps going switching between player 1 and player 2 but nothing prints on the screen

Comment: Printing the board should be done by your `printboard` routine. Are you calling that one inside the play loop?